# Transform an array into arguments of a command?

Tags: bash, parameter, array

I have an array of "options" of a command.

```
my_array=(option1 option2 option3)
```

I want to call this command in a bash script, using the values from array as options. So, `command $(some magic here with my_array) "$1"` becomes:

```
command -option1 -option2 -option3 "$1"
```

How can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: So you want to add `-` to the beginning of each word in `my_array`?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, and execute it. All lines are inside the same bash script. I'm asking this because these same options are going to be used in a lot of places inside the script, so instead of copying all of them around, I thought about an array.

Comment: It might seem pointless but if you are making big shell scripts maybe you should look into perl, this kind of thing is very easy to do there.

Comment: Similar: [Brace expansion with elements of an array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/598719)

Comment: For background, see [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216#286350)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I would prefer a plain `bash` way:

```
command "${my_array[@]/#/-}" "$1"
```

One reason for this are the spaces. For example if you have:

```
my_array=(option1 'option2 with space' option3)
```

The `sed` based solutions will transform it in `-option1 -option2 -with -space -option3` (length 5), but the above `bash` expansion will transform it into `-option1 -option2 with space -option3` (length still 3). Rarely, but sometimes this is important, for example:

```
bash-4.2$ my_array=('Ffoo bar' 'vOFS=fiz baz')
bash-4.2$ echo 'one foo bar two foo bar three foo bar four' | awk "${my_array[@]/#/-}" '{print$2,$3}'
 two fiz baz three
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this variable substitution can’t be wrapped into a function, nor be assigned to a variable, right? It needs to go directly into the command invocation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, you can assign it to other variable as long as you do it as array assignment: `somevar=("${my_array[@]/#/-}")` (Note the parenthesis around the value.) Then of course you have to keep handling it as array when using it: `echo "${somevar[@]}"`. Regarding the functions, there you are too limited by the language's possibilities. You can pass an array: `somefunc "${my_array[@]/#/-}"`, then inside you will have it in `$@`: `function somefunc() { echo "$@"; }`. But same `$@` will contain the other parameters too, if exists, and no other way to return the modified array than stdout.

Comment: Odd enough, doesn't work with zsh. The first time I stumbled upon something that works in bash but not zsh.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, are you sure you used `@` as array subscript? I gave it a test with zsh 5.5.1 and the only difference I noticed what zsh only prefixed each item when written as `${my_array[@]/#/-}`, while bash did it for `*` subscript too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I might have screwed something, indeed works for me!

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this using a temp array in bash:

```
ARR=("option1" "option2" "option3"); ARR2=()
for str in "${ARR[@]}"; do 
   ARR2+=( -"$str" )
done
```

And then in the command-line:

```
command "${ARR2[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't process that it was in an array and was thinking whitespace-separated in a string. This solution will work with that, but given that it's an array, go with manatwork's solution (`@{my_array[@]/#/-}`).

---

This isn't too bad with `sed` and a subshell.  Just how easy the regex is depends on what you can guarantee about the options.  If the options are all one "word" (`a-zA-Z0-9` only), then a simple beginning word boundary (`\<`) will suffice:

```
command $(echo $my_array | sed 's/\</-/g') "$1"
```

If your options have other characters (most likely `-`), you'll need something a bit more complex:

```
command $(echo $my_array | sed 's/\(^\|[ \t]\)\</\1-/g') "$1"
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line, `[ \t]` matches a space or tab, `\|` matches either side (`^` or `[ \t]`), `\(` `\)` groups (for the `\|`) and stores the result, `\<` matches the start of a word.  `\1` begins the replacement by keeping the first match from the parens (`\(\)`), and `-` of course adds the dash we need.

These work with gnu sed, if they don't work with yours, let me know.

And if you'll be using the same thing multiple times, you may want to just calculate it once and store it:

```
opts="$(echo $my_array | sed 's/\(^\|[ \t]\)\</\1-/g')"
...
command $opts "$1"
command $opts "$2"
```

Comment: This didn't work with Mac OS X sed, so I needed to use `gsed` (I installed using `homebrew`). Another thing: instead of `echo $my_array`, I needed to do `echo ${my_array[@]}` to get all items from `my_array`: `echo $my_array` was giving me only the first element. But thanks for the answer and the explanation of the regex, specially about "word boundary", this is extremely useful. :)

Comment: I would like to exit the script if the system's sed isn't compatible with this word boundary feature. How would I do it? Printing sed version and comparing it? From which version of sed this feature was added?

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS My first thought is to check directly whether it works - `[ $(echo x | sed 's/\</y/') == "yx" ] || exit`.

Comment: This is great... we should test about capabilities and not about specific versions. This is great, thank you.

Comment: This will break if any of the array elements contain special characters, most obviously and inexorably whitespace.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS Gilles is right, you should change your accept to manatwork.

Comment: I did it, but thanks anyway for the suggestion and the functionality test. Your solution works, and in my scenario there wasn't elements with whitespace, but for the sake of other people searching this subject on internet, @manatwork's solution is easier, faster and only using bash.

Comment: Will also break if `my_array` is an array, or if it's `-n` or `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[srikanth@myhost ~]$ sh sample.sh 

-option1 -option2 -option3

[srikanth@myhost ~]$ cat sample.sh

#!/bin/bash

my_array=(option1 option2 option3)

echo ${my_array[@]} | sed 's/\</-/g'
```

Comment: Try with the first array element being `n` or `e`.