# What type of operation is /#/- in "${my_array[@]/#/-}"?

Tags: bash, array

The accepted answer to [Transform an array into arguments of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29509/transform-an-array-into-arguments-of-a-command) uses the following Bash command:

> ```
> command "${my_array[@]/#/-}" "$1"
> ```

I'm trying to figure out what the `/#/-` part does, exactly. Unfortunately, I don't know what to call it, so I'm having trouble finding any documentation. I've looked through the Bash man page section on arrays and a few websites, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an instance of pattern replacement in [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): `${parameter/pattern/replacement}` expands `${parameter}`, replacing the first instance of `pattern` with `replacement`. In the context of a pattern of this kind, `#` is special: it anchors the pattern to the start of the parameter. The end result of all this is to expand all the values in the `my_array` array, prepending `-` to each one (by replacing the empty pattern at the start of each parameter).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a pattern replacement in [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) as:

```
${parameter/pattern/replacement}
```

But if the first character after the first `/` is either `/` or `#` or `%` it has the special meaning of `all` (repeated), `start` and `end`.

with:

```
$ str='one_#two_two_three_one'
```

A single `/` will replace the first instance. The first instance of `one`:

```
$ echo "${str/one/x-x}"
x-x_#two_two_three_one
```

Or the first instance of `two`:

```
$ echo "${str/two/x-x}"
one_#x-x_two_three_one
```

The instance of `one` at the end:

```
$ echo "${str/%one/x-x}"
one_#two_two_three_x-x
```

All repetitions of `two`:

```
$ echo "${str//two/x-x}"
one_#x-x_x-x_three_one
```

The instance of `one` at the start:

```
$ echo "${str/#one/x-x}"
x-x_#two_two_three_one
```

An string that start with `#` (quote the `#`):

```
$ echo "${str/\#two/x-x}"
one_x-x_two_three_one
```

But if you leave the # (unquoted) alone, the replacement is set at the beginning of the variable:

```
$ echo "${str/#/====}"
====one_#two_two_three_one
```

Furthermore, if the parameter is an array, the replacement is done on all elements:

```
$ str=( one two three )
$ echo "${str[@]/#/==}"
==one ==two ==three
```

Comment: The wording is a bit misleading as the `#` and `%` are part of the pattern while `//` is a different operator from `/` and use the same patterns.  You can have `pattern='#x'; echo "${var/$pattern}"` (or `${var//$pattern}`), but `pattern=/x; echo "${var/$pattern}"` is not the same as `echo "${var//x}"`. Note that `#` and `%` can be combined in `zsh`, but not `bash` nor `ksh`.