# Brace expansion with elements of an array

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In Bash we can already do this:

```bsh
echo foo.{a,b,c}
# == foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

How do we get roughly:

```bsh
arr=(a b c)
echo foo.{${arr[@]}}
# == foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform an array into arguments of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29509/transform-an-array-into-arguments-of-a-command)

Answer (score 4):

You can use *parameter expansion*

```
$ arr=(a b c)

$ echo "${arr[@]/#/foo.}"
foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

Comment: or `"${arr[@]/@()/foo.}"` (with `extglob`) which would make it also work in ksh93 (where the `${param/pattern/replacement}` operator comes from).

Comment: or `"${arr[@]/+()/foo.}"`, or `"${arr[@]/?()/foo.}"` in ksh/bash, but all will fail in zsh.  @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Isaac, `@(x)`, `+(x)` and `?(x)` are ksh glob operators whose zsh equivalents are `(x)`, `x##` and `(x|)`. To use those ksh glob operators in `zsh`, you'd set the `kshglob` option, though you'd probably only do that as part of the ksh emulation to interpret code intended for `ksh`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The point is still valid: there is no portable solution.

Comment: This works, though I don't suppose it can be pushed all the way. Seems I can do it only once per expression, and it's either prefix or suffix. Otherwise I'd have to invent and maintain "names" for the locations I want to expand each array in and substitute those.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't have to use `bash`:

### `rc`/`es`/`akanga`

(that's the default behaviour):

```
$ arr=(a b c)
$ echo foo.$arr
foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

### `zsh`:

```
$ arr=(a b c)
$ echo foo.$^arr
foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

Or

```
$ set -o rcexpandparam
$ arr=(a b c)
$ echo foo.$arr
foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

(`^` enables `rcexpandparam` for that one expansion, like `=` enables `shwordsplit`, or `~` `globsubst`)

### fish

(also the default behaviour)

```
$ set arr a b c
$ echo foo.$arr
foo.a foo.b foo.c
```

---

All those shells have a better array design than bash's (itself copied from ksh)).

Note that `zsh` and `fish` expansion works like brace expansion. In `rc`, it differs when using `echo $arr.$arr`, which gives:

```
a.a b.b c.c
```

while in `fish`/`zsh -o rcexpandparam`, it gives the same as `echo {a,b,c}.{a,b,c}`, that is:

```
a.a a.b a.c b.a b.b b.c c.a c.b c.c
```

Comment: I wish I could somehow do away with Bash. But probably no shell alternative will do. It'd be easier to port to Python as that's already guaranteed to be installed. But it makes some very common pipelining too cumbersome :/